# Formating caption figure

Tags: floats, formatting, captions

How does one create the following format in TeX:

[image]

**Raw figure:**

[image]

**Raw text :**

If $μ=0$ and $σ=1$, the distribution is called the “standard normal distribution” or the “unit normal distribution” denoted by $N(0,1)$ and a random variable with that distribution is a “standard normal deviate”.

I use the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{Normal.png}
\caption{If $μ=0$ and $σ=1$, the distribution is called the “standard normal distribution” or the “unit normal distribution” denoted by $N(0,1)$ and a random variable with that distribution is a “standard normal deviate”}
\end{figure}
```

but it doesn't yield the format like I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `caption` package, with `labelfont=bf` key for label in bold series and `format=hang` for indent the caption text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,format=hang,labelsep=period}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{If $μ=0$ and $σ=1$, the distribution is called the “standard normal distribution” or the “unit normal distribution” denoted by $N(0,1)$ and a random variable with that distribution is a “standard normal deviate”}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDIT I add `labelsep=period` as suggested by @Very23

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). But I want the caption begins with "Figure 2.1." instead of "Figure 2.1:". How to replace the colon (:) with dot (.)?

Comment: just put in the `\captionsetup` the option `labelsep=period`

Answer (score 1):

Her is an improvement to make the result a little coloser to the post. In particular I changed the font to `fourier+erewhon`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, format=hang, labelsep=period}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth ]{QRZej}
  \caption{If $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, the distribution is called the “standard normal distribution” or the “unit normal distribution” denoted by $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and a random variable with that distribution is a “standard normal deviate”}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]